# React Navigation: Drawer Navigator showing up in background

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

Im using the [DrawerNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html), from React Navigation. I've noticed sometimes I can see the `Drawer Navigator` open behind certain "views" for example, just before I open the camera or when asking the user for permissions.

Below is a simplified example (code) of my `DrawerNavigator`.
I was wondering how I could hide the `DrawerNavigator`, in the background.

```
import { createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";


import FAQ from "./FAQ";
import Home from "./Home";


const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home
    },

    FAQ: {
      screen: FAQ
    }
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
export default App;
```

An example image.

[image: An example of this can be seen here.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error turned out be related to this line `this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });`. Which sets the app state i.e. if the app is in focus or in the background. Removing this line seems to fix my issue with the `DrawerNavigator`.

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this.appInFocus);
    this.setState({
      appState: AppState.currentState
    });
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", this.appInFocus);
  };

  appInFocus = async (nextAppState: PossibleAppStates) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === "active"
    ) {
       console.log("HELLo")
    }
    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

useNativeAnimations: false, working for me !

Answer (score 1):

You can close it manually before starting anything.

```
To open and close drawer, use the following helpers to open and close the drawer:

this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to close the drawer,

Import the `DrawerActions` from "react-navigation"

```
import { DrawerActions } from "react-navigation";
.....

this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
```